# Python - Selenium .text solve mathematics formula

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the site there is a specific class that contains a math formula like :

7 - 6 =

15 x 8 =

3 x (5 - 2) =

...

```
<div tabindex="20" dir="ltr" class="card-title">3 x (5 - 2) =</div>
```

How can I export the the element content in Selenium and solvet it?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
PATH = "H:/python/venv/chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'H:/python/venv/chromedriver.exe')



driver.get("https://freerice.com/categories/basic-math-pre-algebra")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
feladat = str(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]").text)
megoldas = [feladat]
lista = []
for c in feladat:
    if c.isdigit():
        lista = lista + [c]
    else:
        lista = lista + [c]
print(lista)
```

Comment: Not sure why this got 4 downvotes and no comments!   You had a go, you had a direction, you asked for help. You just didn't know there was an `eval` or `exec` function. That's an OK question in my book.  I hope the answer below serves you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see where your solution was going - to split out all the characters, identify digits and then (i assume) you would find all the mathematical operators...

There is an easier way.

The `eval` and `exec` functions takes in a string and computes the output. As long as that string is valid then it will work.

I used `eval` as i typed it first and it worked.  Google the two if you need to know more about them.

Based on your inputs:

```
7 - 6 =
15 x 8 =
3 x (5 - 2) =
```

And typical syntax is `x = 1 + 1`.
We need to:

- remove the "=" a the end.
- we need to add a return variable into the start.

We do this as folows:

```py
#Your string - the most complex one you provided
inputText = "3 x (5-2) = "

#remove the = by splitting on it and then essentially taking everything to the left
inputText = inputText.split("=")[0]

# x is a character, * is the operator   - Any other data might need processing here
inputText = inputText.replace("x", "*")

#Create an empty variable called "answer"
answer= ""

#build a string line "myVariable = 1 + 1"
appendText = "answer = " + inputText

#execute the string. 
exec(appendText)

#output the answer
print (answer)
```

The output is:

> 9

Looking at your site, and keeping it in line with your current approach, I would update it as follows:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://freerice.com/categories/basic-math-pre-algebra")

#OK cookies button
OKButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa='oil-YesButton']")))
OKButton.click()

inputText = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card-title']")))
inputText = inputText.text.split("=")[0]
inputText = inputText.replace("x", "*")
answer = ""
appendText = "answer = "+ inputText
exec(appendText)

answer = int(answer)  #remove any added float when doing division
print (answer)

#find the div that has the answer and click it
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='" + str(answer) + "']").click()
```

I also updated the identifiers to be more easily understood.

Comment: Thank you :) , there is an error in the bottom code , I got 6.0 number but there is no 6.0 only 6 in the ,,list,,(website) , how can I solve this?

Comment: Depends what the input is? I ran this code and it worked fine... Can you help me out with more detail? Which number? Answer or input?

Comment: So , when the question have a / , the correct answer is 10 but the output is 10.0

output:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[text()='10.0']"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)

Comment: You didn't put a divide in your quesiton, so i didn't compensate for that :-)   .... When you divide python converts you initial variant type data to a float. We want rid of the decimal so we can convert to a int  .... i'll add it into the above for you

Comment: i added `answer = int(answer)`  -  if you think this is the right answer to your question don't forget to mark is at the right answer and upvote

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)